# Docusign Connect for Salesforce with custom URL

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a client with a Salesforce environment at a custom URL: https://_______.my.salesforce.com, and while I was able to install the Docusign package, I cannot seem to get it to connect to my demo/dev account for the last step of initial setup.

When I'm on Docusign's Connect settings and I use the custom URL option, I get an error that returns with some HTML from the page and no matter what alternate options I select I cannot get it to connect. I have verified that the Docusign IP addresses are set up properly on Salesforce's side to allow access.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up a custom Salesforce URL for Connect the URL must point to the API endpoint - not the login page.  So, for example, you'd use something like this:

https://_______.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/34.0/